# Cognito web token generation using golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I need to generate a token with cognito using golang and attach the token it to the api. I tried surfing through internet, I was very much confused. Is there any golang package to do this.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/

Comment: Who is the token for?